# How to get the "No Charge D.U.N.S. Number" registering for developer program as a company

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

We have newly started the iPhone application development in our company so we need a developer account enrollment , while registering that we come to know that we must have D.U.N.S. number assigned by D&B , so for checking whether our organization has assigned that number or not we followed the look up of D.U.N.S. number from https://developer.apple.com/ios/enroll/dunsLookupForm.action , as we do not found our organization's name listed there, we applied for the D.U.N.S. number to D&B's head office of India located in city Mumbai. 
   They asked us to pay for the 30,000 Rs.(Indian currency) for getting the D.U.N.S. number but, when i googled for that as per apples standards i got the information at link https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/D-U-N-S.html which says that apple developers enrollment do not requires the paid D.U.N.S. number , we are trying to get **"No Charge D.U.N.S. Number"** from a long time to enroll for the developer program as a company . If any one have the specific way to get No Charge D.U.N.S. Number then please help us.

Comment: This *might* be off-topic for SO. I've found you can just use https://iupdate.dnb.com/iUpdate/companylookup.htm . Then search for your company, if it's not found there will be a "Get a DUNS number" button. However, when I try it now, for country it only lets me choose USA. But it's worth a shot. When I did mine I had to call them, and they tried (fruitlessly) to sell me all sorts of credit services that are not required to just get a DUNS number. But again that's just my experience here in America. Good luck.

Comment: @ NJones : Same here Jones, i make a calle at Head Office D&B India , then they asked me to pay 30k for a year, then, by other way i had a mailing with their one of representative, asking for the No Charge DUNS which we require for the developer enrollment program as a company, then he asked me to pay for 8 k, I am totally confused that how to go through this. :(

Comment: @iShwar we are stuck with the same problem. Could you let me know finally what you did?

Comment: @NJones : How did you manage to get no charge DUNS number at last?

Comment: @iShwar, can you please let me know what was the ultimate solution as we are stuck with the same issue.

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni : Yes, The No charge DUNS number is free of cost for US and might be for few other countries too, But for India they apply the processing charges... and we have to pay that amount, last time when i bought it for organisation where i was working at that time the cost for No Charge DUNS number was around 8K, And the concern office is DUNS's office in Mumbai, they elaborate whole the process once we connected with them.